# Prolog: Delete last list element

Tags: list, prolog

I succeeded to reverse a list:

```
reverse([],Z,Z).
reverse([H|T],Z,A) :- reverse(T,Z,[H|A]).
```

and I want a program that deletes the last element of a list.

Comment: You could (1) reverse the list, remove the head, then reverse again, or (2) use the `append/3` predicate (hint: use the last element of the list as a single element list for the second argument), or (3) write a simple recursion that omits the last element when you get to the end (hint: a base case would be `remove_last([_], ?)` what would `?` be?). Option 1 here would be the least efficient.

Comment: Think you to reverse the list before delete the last element is a good idea

Comment: Like I said, option 1 is probably the least desirable idea. It's just easy to conceive.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to reverse anything?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% remove_last(IN_LIST, OUT_LIST).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% 1. No last element to remove, fail - cut stops alternatives
remove_last([], []) :- !, fail.

% 2. Only one element in list - return empty list - cut stops alternatives
remove_last([_], []) :- !.

% 3. If the rules above did not match, preserve the head of the
% list in the result list and recurse...
remove_last([X | T], [X | T2]) :-
    remove_last(T, T2).
```